# Word boundary not working despite raw string

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings and I am trying to run a regex search on it.

I use:

```
re.search(r"\b" + word + r"\b", list[item], re.I)
```

Yet, the result of the search doesn't take into account the word boundaries and still returns wrong results. 
Example:

when word is `try` and i run the test, it still returns True for `trying` or `country`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear. I iterate through each string in the list

Comment: `re.search(r"\b" + "try" + r"\b", "Country", re.I)` is `None`, `re.search(r"\b" + "try" + r"\b", "try for free", re.I)` is a match. It looks fine to me.

Comment: Dunno, works for me. Can you show an example where it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, your pattern looks fine.

Minor quip though--if you have a list of strings, you can simply do this instead:

```
for string in string_list:
    result = re.search(r"\b" + word + r"\b", string, re.I)
```

It avoids using the built-in Python function `list`.